# How to ignore search queries when pushing a new path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

#### Problem

I want to push a new path as an addition to the URI where search queries are set.

Example:

Current location: `https://example.com/foo?bar=123&foobar=123`

When I call `history.push('newPath')` I will end up with `https://example.com/newPath`. What I want to get, however, is `https://example.com/foo/newPath`.

One solution would be to call `history.push('foo/newPath')` or if I would save the current path and add the wanted path (`newPath`) on top, but I was hoping that `history.push` might have a way to handle this?

Comment: No, it does not, you will have to either push 'foo/newPath' or save the current path and the add whatever you want after it, like you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to push a new path as an addition to the URI where search
> queries are set.

To change/append the path you can use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) which won't affect your query parameters.

```
// maybe from window.location.href?
const href = 'https://example.com/foo?bar=123&foobar=12'

let url = new URL(href)
url.pathname = url.pathname + '/newPath'

console.log(url) // https://example.com/foo/newPath?bar=123&foobar=12
```